# API Platform Did not show First Name And Last Name Upon normalizationContext and denormalizationContext

Tags: rest, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am new to API Platform and I have some problem with normalizationContext and denormalizationContext for my User Entity on the API platform. When I added the normalizationContext and denormalizationContext to ApiResources, and yes I did add in as `@Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})` above my first_name and last_name variable. But when trying to post data from the api platform, I didn't see my first_name and last_name variable option.

[image]

This is my User entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"user:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"user:write"}},
 * )
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Groups({"user:write"})
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $last_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $dob;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $first_name): self
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $last_name): self
    {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDob(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dob;
    }

    public function setDob(\DateTimeInterface $dob): self
    {
        $this->dob = $dob;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I wanted to available first_name and last_name variable to the API platform for both read and write group. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think it could be the underscores in first_name and last_name.
There is an option in the config called naming strategy, so you can force Doctrine to read underscores properly. But then it has to be consistent over all entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use camelcase for properties. Doctrine expect camelcase by default. Doctrine didn't recognize getFirstName() as the getter for $first_name. And since the property is declared private api-platform is not able to get the value.

this should work:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $firstName;    

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }
```

or you can try to force doctrine to use underscore like so:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

Comment: and read this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#naming-conventions

Comment: Just a little update from May 2023. I had everything written correctly and I had cache on dev environment so in my case after I cleared the cache, properties I added groups to, showed up in the response. Just to have it in mind if anyone else falls on the same problem.